# How to write a common generic function for different classes?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, generic-programming

```
func setPostcommentData(postmodel:model1,index: IndexPath) {
     btnReply.tag = index.section
     lblName.text = postmodel.getFullName()
     btnReply.setTitle("Reply", for: UIControlState.normal)
     btnCount.setTitle("0", for: UIControlState.normal)
     TxtViewComment.text = postmodel.description
     lblTime.text = ChatDates.commentTimeData(postmodel.createdDate).dateString
}
```

Usage:

```
cellComment.setPostcommentData(postmodel: model1,index:indexPath) 
cellComment.setPostcommentData(postmodel: model2,index:indexPath) 
cellComment.setPostcommentData(postmodel: model3,index:indexPath)
```

How to write generic function so that it accepts different models and sets data?

Comment: Please show how you set data with other models. If the code is very different from model to model, I don't recommend making it generic.

Comment: Every model Inherit From Basemodel . All Model Are Child Class of basemodel and Every Model Have 2-3 Different Property also From Basemodel. @Sweeper

Comment: if function accepts `ParentModel` it also accepts all `Childs`

Comment: Child Have Some Other Variable Also Which Are Different From Parent . Need To Access That Variable Also In Generic function . @JuicyFruit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the idea right, here is a solution

```
protocol PostComment {
    var value1: String {get}
    var value2: String {get}
    var value3: String {get}
}

class PostCommentParent: PostComment {
    var value1: String {
        return self.myValue1
    }

    var value2: String {
        return self.myValue2
    }

    var value3: String {
        return self.myValue3
    }

    var myValue1 = "1"
    var myValue2 = "2"
    var myValue3 = "3"
}

class PostCommentChild: PostCommentParent {
    override var value3: String {
        return self.myValue4
    }

    var myValue4 = "4"
}

let myParent = PostCommentParent()
let myChild = PostCommentChild()

func parse(comment: PostComment) {
    print(comment.value3)
}

parse(comment: myChild)
parse(comment: myParent)
```

Comment: @Amey sorry, it is impossible to understand, what do you mean.